# Copying images to another directory using command line arguments bash

Tags: bash

I'm really new to bash and I'm trying to write a script to loop through all pictures in a directory and copy them individually to a different directory. I'm not really familiar with syntax, so I can't really figure out what I'm doing wrong.

```
func ()
{
FILES=$1
FILES+=/*.jpg
for f in $FILES
do
   echo "$f"
   cp "$f" $2

done;
}
func $1 $2
```

If i enter arguments like
    `script ./images ./test` 
it echos every image as

```
/images/image1.jpg
/images/image2.jpg
```

and so on, but it's not actually copying them to the test directory. Any ideas on what the problem could be?

Comment: why not `cp *.jpg /path/to/destination_dir/` ? (Unless  your filenames have spaces in them). `cp` is designed to work that way. you may be able to read your on-line documenation from cmd-line by typing `man cp`. Good luck.

Comment: Actually, I tried your code and it worked as you expected. It copied 2 jpg files  to test folder. Could it be that you are not running your code where `test` folder resides

Comment: Thanks for confirming it for me. I was running it on a server and the directories weren't properly refreshing I guess, but it actually was working, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

> I'm trying to write a script to loop through all pictures in a
>   directory and copy them individually to a different directory

You may use the `find` command like this

```
find path_to_your_directory -type f -name *.jpg -exec cp {} where_to_copy \;
```

As @shelter mentioned you could use `cp *.jpg /path/to/destination_dir/` but in this case you have to write some extra code to take case of the files with spaces say `file with spaces.jpg`.

But `find` takes care of it automatically.

Comment: Thanks for this. Find works much better and I'm gonna try to replace the loop.